# Is there a dynamic way to split 100 into different values?

Tags: c#, logic

I am stuck in a scenario which is complex for me to implement. Scenario is : I have rows in excel sheet which is dynamic . sometimes it could be 2, sometimes 5, sometimes 12 means any number of rows could be there. i need to assign different unique values to each available row in such a way that their sum should be equal to 100. Example : if i have 2 rows i can assign values 65 and 35 but not 50 to both as the value needs to be unique. similarly if i have 4 rows i need to assign values like 20,30, 27, 23 .Need a c# code for this.

How can i do this?

Comment: Your *"ASAP"* has no effect, meaning, or value here... However, you should take excel out of your problem completely, and try to solve this with just code first. Then when you know how to solve that, you can work on integrating it

Comment: SO is not for solving riddles, exam tasks and contest problems. What did you try so far? If you can show some code with a specific issue, then the community might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you could generate different random numbers for each row. The way I generated the numbers was with `DateTime.Now.Second` and `DateTime.Now.Minute`. To ensure that the numbers never go over 100, you can subtract from the maximum number in the row. This is the general idea:
`

```
   public static ulong CapAtNumber(ulong num, ulong cap) {   
        
    while(num>cap)
        {

            num = (num / 2) - 2;
            if (num < 3)
            {
                num += (Convert.ToUInt64(DateTime.Now.Minute) + Convert.ToUInt64(DateTime.Now.Second) /  2);
            }
        }
      
        return num;
    }
```

`This is an example of how you would find the maximum. I used the Math group to check for maximums among two`ulong` numbers. The numbers are A B C D E F, and so on, and I group them into AB CD EF to find the maximum between the groups. The array size gets cut in half each time until the array size is 1. When the array size is 1, the number in the array is the maximum.

```
public static ulong[] FindTheMaxOfArray(ulong[] arg)
    {
        bool repeat = true;

        ulong checknumber = 100;
        while(repeat == true)
        {
            if (arg.Length % 2 == 0)
            {
                var halflist = new ulong[arg.Length / 2];
                for (int z = 0; z < arg.Length / 2; z += 2)
                {
                    
                    halflist[z] = Math.Max(arg[z], arg[z + 1]);
                    if (
                        halflist.Length == 1)
                    {
                        repeat = true;
                        arg = new ulong[halflist.Length];
                        arg = halflist; 
                    }
                    else { repeat = false; 
                        checknumber = halflist[0]; }

                }
               
            }
            else
            {
                var halflist = new ulong[arg.Length + 1 / 2];
                for (int z = 0; z < halflist.Length; z++)
                {
                    if (z % 2 != 0)
                    {
                        if (z != halflist.Length - 2)
                        {
                            halflist[z] = Convert.ToUInt64(Math.Max(Math.Max(arg[z], arg[z + 1]), arg[z + 2]));
                        }
                        else { halflist[z] = Convert.ToUInt64(Math.Max(arg[z], arg[z + 1])); }

                    }

                }
                if (halflist.Length == 1)
                {
                    repeat = true;
                    arg = new ulong[halflist.Length];
                    arg = halflist;

                }
                
                else { checknumber = halflist[0];
                    repeat = false; 
                }

            }
        }
            
       for(int z=0; z<arg.Length; z++)
        {
            if (arg[z] == checknumber)
            {
                arg[z] = CapAtNumber(arg[z], arg[z] - 20);
            }
        }
        return arg;
    }
```

if you want to ensure that there are no repeats, you can create a method to check for that. Each number in the foreach loop is checking with the numbers in the for loop. Since these are the same arrays, there has to be at least one repeat that happens naturally. Everything except this part seems to run smoothly. Here is an example

```
public static ulong[] Checkforrepeats(ulong[] args)
    {
        ulong repeatednumber = 1000;
        int repeat = -1;
       
        foreach( ulong num in args)
        {
            for(int z = 0; z<args.Length; z++)
            {
                if(z == 0)
                { repeat = -1; }
                if(num ==args[z])
                {
                    repeat += 1; //repeat was set to -1 to counter act the guaranteed repeat that will happen 

                }
                if (repeat == 2)
                {
                    args[z] += 2;
                    args[z - 1] -= 2;
                   
                }
            }
        }
        return args;
    }
```

Comment: The `DateTime` elements need a bit of changing depending on how random you want it to be.